QGIS - 2 value relation fields - automatically update the second one
I am working with two field that are using the value-relation widget.
The first field named "Cd_Hab" lists the content of "IDC" from the layer "HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS".
The second field, named "habitat" lists the content of "lib_physio" from the layer "HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS", with a filter on idc.
Here is the filter:
array_intersect(
    array_distinct(
        string_to_array("IDC", ',')
    ),
    array_distinct(
        string_to_array(
            replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    current_value('Cd_Hab'), '[{"}]', ''
                ),
                ',', ' '
            ),
            ' '
        )
    )
)

The content of the second field depends on the content of the first field.
So, if the first field is modified, the content of the second one should also change.
But, currently, the second field is only updated if I clic on it.
On the first picture, you can see 'E' and 'F' (Cd_hab) are associated to 'CCC' and 'Pinèdes[...]'. (habitat)

Now, on the second picture, on the fourth row, you can see 'F' is unselected; only 'E' remain.
But the association with 'F' is still visible in "habitat"

Finally, when I simply click on the 'habitat' field, the list is automatically updated, and 'Pinède[...]' is no longer selected. The content is now accurate.

My question:
How can I make sure that the field "habitat" is automatically updated in order to avoid having to clic on it to update it?

I was unable to find an alternative solution, so I opted for a SQLite trigger.
Whenever the cd_hab field is updated, this trigger will automatically update the habitat field by reconstructing the list based on the values currently available in habitat. Values that do not meet the specified criteria will be excluded from the aggregation.
CREATE TRIGGER updt_cd_hab
AFTER UPDATE OF cd_hab ON ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS
    SET habitat = (
        SELECT '{' || GROUP_CONCAT(HA.idc_lib, ',') || '}'
        FROM HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS HA
        WHERE NEW.habitat LIKE '%' || HA.idc_lib || '%'
        AND NEW.cd_hab LIKE '%' || HA.idc || '%')
    WHERE pk = NEW.pk;
END;

